I'm trying to implement an Infinite Scroll for performance purposes in my project, but I can't see good outcomings
I don't know how to implement IonInfiniteScroll correctly or how to put the limit of the content to have better performance
I try to "render" or "show" initially 20 elements for example on the screen, and when I start to scroll and getting close to the last element, load more elements, but the only thing I get, All the content is displayed at once and this greatly affects the performance of the devices
The project is in: Ionic 7 with Angular 17
here is the Service.ts:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable, catchError, of } from 'rxjs';



@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class ConsumoApiService {

  private baseUrl: string = "URL:PORT";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }



   getNotificaciones (peticion : string):Observable<any[]>{

     return this.http.get<any[]>(`${ this.baseUrl }/${ peticion }`);
  }

}

The Html tab1.html:
<!-- Contenido principal -->

<ion-content [fullscreen]="true" class="ion-padding">
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of Notificaciones; let i = index">
    <ion-label>

      <ion-grid  >
        <span>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col col-8>
                <h2 text-wrap>{{item.responsable}}</h2>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col col-2>
                <h4><span class="FechaLogo" [ngStyle]="{'color': '#488aff'}">{{item.fecha }}</span></h4>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row *ngIf="item.accion != ''">
            <ion-col>
                <p *ngIf = "item.tipo == 1" [ngStyle] = "{'color': 'red'}" text-wrap>{{item.accion}}</p>
                <p *ngIf = "item.tipo != 1" text-wrap>{{item.accion}}</p>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col>
                    <p text-wrap><span>{{item.tema_descr}}<span *ngIf="(item.tipo == 1 || item.tipo == 2 || item.tipo == 4) && item.encabezado != ''"> - No.{{item.encabezado}}</span><p *ngIf="(item.tipo == 3 || item.tipo == 5 || item.tipo == 6) && item.encabezado != ''">{{item.encabezado}}</p></span></p> 
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col>
                <p [ngStyle]="{'color': '#488aff'}" text-wrap>{{item.proyecto_nombre}}</p>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row> 
        <ion-row *ngIf="item.estatus != '' ">
            <ion-col>
                 <p class="Texto" [ngStyle] = "{'color': item.estatus_color}" text-wrap>{{item.estatus}}</p>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>                         
        <ion-row *ngIf="item.monto > 0 ">
                <ion-col>
                     <p class="Texto" text-wrap>$<span data-format="#.000">{{item.monto | number}}</span></p>
                </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        </span>
    </ion-grid>
<img class="imagenItem" *ngIf="item.imagen != '' && item.parametro_imagen == '1'" [src]="returnPathFile(item.imagen)" alt="">

    </ion-label>

       </ion-item>
</ion-list>  

<!-- Implementacion del Scroll -->

<ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="loadData($event)">
 <ion-infinite-scroll-content 
 loadingSpiner="Crescent"
 loadingText="Cargando...">
 </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
</ion-infinite-scroll>

</ion-content>
<ion-footer>
</ion-footer>

Tab1.ts:
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ConsumoApiService } from ".././services/consumoapi";
import { InfiniteScrollCustomEvent, IonInfiniteScroll } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab1',
  templateUrl: './tab1.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tab1.page.scss'],
})
export class Tab1Page implements OnInit {
  public Notificaciones : any[] = [];
  data: any[] = Array(20);

  constructor(private servicio :  ConsumoApiService) { 
    console.log("Constructor");
  }


  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("ngOnInit");
      this.servicio.getNotificaciones("notificaciones/filtro/gp_constructora/osfe").subscribe( rs=> {
          this.Notificaciones = rs;
      });
  }


  returnPathFile(file : string){
        return  "URL:PORT/"+"CONSTRUCTORA"+"/"+file;
    }
  
  loadData (event: any) {
    console.log('Cargando...');

    setTimeout(() => {

      const nuevoArreglo = Array(20)
      this.data.push( ...nuevoArreglo);
      event.target.complete();

    }, 1000 );

    } 
}

